# Error code: 1824 Failed to open the refernced table [table exists]

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a foreign key constraint, but I'm getting [Error Code: 1824: *Failed to open the refrenced table* 'agent_agent']

the table **agent_agent** exists in my database, I can't get my head around this issue.

I tried creating the constraint using the graphical mode of mysql workbench and I'm getting the same error.

`select * from agent_agent;` return the data, so the table exists in the DB but:

```
ALTER TABLE demande_contact
ADD CONSTRAINT dddd
FOREIGN KEY (agent_id_id) REFERENCES agent_agent(id);
```

is returning an error 1824.

Edit: Here's the 2 tables DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `agent_agent` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `matricule` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `nom_et_prenom` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `fonction` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `structure` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `poste_org` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `metier` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `csp` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `en_activite` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `service` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `centre_cout` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `agent_agent_user_id_bfcb5c50` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=628 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `demande_contact` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `telephone` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `agent_id_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `demande_id_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `demande_contact_demande_id_id_0abc00b0_fk_demande_d` (`demande_id_id`),
  KEY `agent_id_id_constraint_idx` (`agent_id_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `demande_contact_demande_id_id_0abc00b0_fk_demande_d` FOREIGN KEY (`demande_id_id`) REFERENCES `demande_demandetransport` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please add the table definition for both tables and confirm they are both in the same db schema.

Comment: Just add the table structure here.

Comment: @P.Salmon: Yes, they are in the same db schema

Comment: After posting the DDL, I've noticed that my 2 tables use different engines, I re-created the second table using the MyISAM Engine and now the constraint creation instruction is working fine. Thanks guys